# What's the best way to clip a bitmap using its inscribed ellipse

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, system.drawing

I'd like to take a bitmap with an ARGB 32 pixel format and clip it so that the contents within its inscribed ellipse remain, and anything outside the ellipse turns into ARGB(0,0,0,0).
I could do it programmatically using GetPixel and SetPixel and some trigonometry to figure out which pixel is out of bounds - but I suspect there's a better, more built-in way to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can start looking at [Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alessandro D'Andria for pointing out the region part - I've figured out the rest:

```
    public Bitmap Rasterize()
    {
        Bitmap ringBmp = new Bitmap(width: _size.Width, height: _size.Height, format: PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

        //Create an appropriate region from the inscribed ellipse
        Drawing2D.GraphicsPath graphicsEllipsePath = new Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        graphicsEllipsePath.AddEllipse(0, 0, _size.Width, _size.Height);

        Region ellipseRegion = new Region(graphicsEllipsePath);

        //Create a graphics object from our new bitmap
        Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(ringBmp);

        //Draw a resized version of our image to our new bitmap while using the highest quality interpolation and within the defined ellipse region
        gfx.InterpolationMode = Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
        gfx.SmoothingMode = Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.PixelOffsetMode = Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        gfx.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
        gfx.Clear(Color.Transparent);
        gfx.Clip = ellipseRegion;
        gfx.DrawImage(image: _image, rect: new Rectangle(0, 0, _size.Width, _size.Height));

        //Dispose our graphics
        gfx.Dispose();

        //return the resultant bitmap
        return ringBmp;
    }
```

Apparently it is extremely important to set PixelOffsetMode to HighQuality, because otherwise the DrawImage method would crop parts of the resulting image.